# Gibbs phenonemon in real life

Tags: filter, low-pass, fourier, bandwidth, square

If I feed a square wave into a first order, passive, low-pass filter (resistor and capacitor), I get the following results on an oscilloscope (sorry, I don't know how to scale and rotate images):

[image: Input and output of low-pass filter]
[image: The low-pass filter circuit]

Why does the overshoot only occur on half of the corners of the square wave? Based on Fourier analysis, partial sums of a square wave should look something like this:

[image]

This is the Gibbs phenomenon. Here the overshoot occurs on all 'corners' of the square wave, rather than just the ones following a transition. I got some similar results when testing the frequency response of a unity gain buffer op amp:

[image]
[image]

Hypothetically, the op amp acts as a low-pass filter due to its finite bandwidth, so it's not surprising that it produces similar results to the actual low-pass filter above.

My question is: based on electrical theory, low-pass filtering should produce a square wave with attenuated higher harmonics, which should produce something similar to the Gibbs phenomenon with overshoot at each of the corners. Why doesn't this happen here? For me, it makes MATHEMATICAL sense that the output wave should have overshoot at each corner, but it makes INTUITIVE sense that the output should only have overshoot at the corners that occur after a transition. Why? Because if the 'ringing' (overshoot/undershoot) also occurred BEFORE a transition, it would seem *non-causal* - it would almost be as if the wave is guessing that it's about to transition!

How can I reconcile my understanding from the perspective of Fourier theory with what actually happens in real life?

Comment: You're more likely looking at an improperly compensated probe than a Gibb's phenomenon

Comment: The op amp and passive filter were tested in two different labs with two different probes. You would expect overshoot/some distortion to occur anyway, wouldn't you? Even if the probes were nicely compensated.

Comment: Gibbs phenomenon is because of summation of frequency components of the Fourier series.  It's more than just overshoot. You're not doing anything that should result in Gibbs phenomenon.

Comment: Try moving the 'scope probe ground lead with a separate short (1"-ish) wire right to the end of the capacitor instead of wherever it it going now.

Comment: @Scott Really? The filter should attenuate higher frequency components, shouldn't it? Sure, it's not a brick wall filter, but it should still have similar looking results to a partial sum.

Comment: Analog filters might or might not overshoot.  It is not Gibbs.  You're misapplying the term

Comment: Why is it not Gibbs? Higher frequency components are attenuated. Really high harmonics should practically be zero, with some transition band in between - so it should be similar to a partial sum, should it not? Why would it not look similar to the Gibbs phenomenon?

Comment: It's not Gibbs, because you're not in any way representing a discontinuous signal with a finite sum of frquencies.  "Looks like Gibbs"  is not Gibbs.  The term has a meaning, and it doesn't apply here.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that something similar to the Gibbs phenomenon would occur in the limit as a transition became instant, not just when it was instant. *Hypothetically*, if I could generate a pure square wave input, would I see the Gibbs phenomenon then?

Comment: No, you would not, because the Gibbs phenomenon is non-causal.

Comment: But *why* would you not? What would a derivation look like in circuit analysis that would indicate this? Maybe it's because the filter shifts phase as well as attenuate higher frequencies?

Comment: A first order (RC) filter by itself does not produce ringing. The ringing you are seeing is caused by parasitic L and C somewhere. It is even possible that the ringing occurs in the 'scope probe, but not in the actual circuit. It is very common to see phantom ringing on oscilloscope plots of a square wave.

Comment: The trace doesn't look like a "low pass filter". Maybe you should submit your filter schematics to start. You have 10V p-p in, and 100mV p-p out, a 100X attenuation. What are the values of R and C?

Comment: I did misplace one of the orange leads. which measured voltage at the wrong point. I fixed it and the result is the same, which indicates that the resistor's impedance was much smaller than the capacitor's impedance. This doesn't really matter though, since it's the product RC that determines the filter characteristics. Thanks for all of your comments, I may have figured it out now. I testing out some theory using MATLAB scripts and if the results turn out nicely, I might write an answer myself.

Comment: *I might write an answer myself* - I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: The imbalance in the overshoot indicates some non-linear behavior. What is it?

Comment: Why do you expect ringing before a step change has occurred? Can we foresee the future?

Comment: Simple enough, Gibbs phenomenon is anticausal and hence cannot be realised. It's just a theoretical effect coming from as physically not realisable filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! I created a MATLAB script which sums the first 1000 terms of the output's Fourier series with a 1Hz square wave input. Here's the answer:

Low-pass filters *can* cause the Gibbs phenomenon to occur, but these filters are not physically realizable. (This makes sense, otherwise non-causal behavior would be possible). Consider a brick wall filter. This is equivalent to truncating the Fourier series of the input to a certain maximum frequency. The results of the MATLAB script verify this:

[image]

As mkeith said in the comments, a perfect first order RC filter does not produce ringing. Instead, the filter just 'rounds off' the square wave:

[image]

The filter that I created was a first order filter, but parasitic elements, bad probes, etc. must have produced the ringing/overshoot, since as the result from MATLAB above shows - first order low-pass filters do not produce ringing.

However, second order (RLC) low-pass filter can produce ringing! The MATLAB script verifies this:

[image]

You'll notice that there is no non-causal behavior occurring here. This second-order filter is physically realizable (neglecting parasitic elements, but even then this behavior should be able to be approximately reproduced).

This means that the reason I was confused was simply because I didn't do the maths! I assumed that the Gibbs phenomenon would apply to a first order filter despite the fact that phase-shifting and attenuation occur in a first order filter which do not occur when truncating the Fourier series.

Comment: Please take some time to read and digest all the comments to your OP. You'll get to understand that Gibbs phenomenon has nothing to do with it.

Comment: truncating harmonics  –the Fourier series

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fctUcU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

### Non-causal system

- anticipates the future values.
- the present change depends on future changes

The 2nd signal above in red is a screen copy of [Falstad's](http://www.falstad.com/fourier/) Fourier analysis of a square wave.  With a slider option for truncated harmonics, the resulting signal is shown in red a ringing before the transition.  This an example of non-causal.  However, a real brick wall filter has a large phase shift and group delay which causes the amplitude changes to occur only AFTER the input change.

This makes a real filter, a causal system as opposed to truncating a Fourier series.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer.... It's just pictures

Comment: It is an answer, but laconic. It says: adjust C1 and watch the waveforms change shape from exponentially rising, to square, to exponentially peaking. But, I agree, some words could have been added, given the OP's content.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen i understand what you're saying, but to the majority of people, they will just see pictures with no explanation. To me, that isn't a *good* answer. Therefore it is not a useful answer, hence my -1. I see it as almost the same as a 'Link only' answer. It needs some text and an explanation to be considered useful

Comment: For the record, the correct answers are beside each photo.  If I have time , I’ll explain why a C  ratio error looks similar but different to a probe ground resonance overshoot. This is one case where the OP is wise enough to know Gibb’s so  I left out fundamentals he should know.

Comment: @MCG it's cool that you think others are more stupid than you are. Trust me, if you understood, no reason others can't. In any case they can ask by themselves.

Comment: @Gregory I'm not thinking others are more 'stupid' at all. That's a silly assumption. Any answers that are just pictures with no explanations are not good answers. Simple as that. An explanation will help anyone understand. I'd say that on any question, no matter how simple or difficult it is

Comment: You would. But you said " i understand what you're saying, but to the majority of people". Anyway, short and clear answer is always better than those blankets people print sometimes, pouring a whole university course here.

Comment: Yes. I did say the majority of people. The majority of people probably would want explanations. And yes, short and clear is good. This is short but not *clear* to most as it has no explanations. It is just pictures. Which makes for a bad answer